# Why Each user can modify flag field of other users by VBO(Views Bulk Operation)?

Tags: 7, entities, flags, views

I have many users, and I have a flag and also flag field. users can flag contents and add value in flag field when they are flagging a content. for modifying flag field I'm using [VBO Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations). But each user can modify flag field of other users. Consider Jack and John flagged a content, in this situation John can modify flag field of Jack and himself.

I want to users only can modify their flag fields. John can modify her flag field and Jack can modify her flag field too.

**Update**

When John logins to site, He could see below situation in site. I mean, John also can modify Jack's field value. This situation is possible for Jack and others.

[image]

Comment: Add more technical details in this, all that can be said by now is: reconstruct your views accordingly or implement a hook and conditionally show or hide a VBO option.

Comment: You should also check the permissions for your flags.

Comment: @mchar I added more info about question. Is it enough?

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. I checked permission too, it's not about it